# Evince slow due to apparmor denying access to ~/.cache being a symlink

Tags: permissions, evince

Evince shows PDF documents and needs fonts.

### Context: `~/.cache` symlinked by administrator

Users directory here are split between a "clean" part and a "messy" part.
The idea is to care more about the "clean" parts (backup etc) and less about the "messy" parts.

The users' `~/.cache` is a symlink to the messy part.

### Symptom: slow start

This causes evince to start slowly: 20 seconds wait before any window appear.
After the window appears, things seem normal.

### Investigation

- `strace` shows that during the first 2 seconds, it tries a lot to access files in `~/.cache/fontconfig` and `/var/cache/fontconfig` that fail with `EACCESS`
- then it spends about 18 seconds enumerating data in `/usr/share/fonts`
- `~/.cache/fontconfig` is readable and writable by user, `/var/cache/fontconfig` does not exist.

### Interpretation

Similar issues (e.g. [Evince...(Permission denied) - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344834/evince-document-viewer-failed-to-execute-child-process-nemo-permission-deni/363188) ) strongly suggest that [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) is involved.

### How to fix?

- Some invite to [disable AppArmor for evince](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344834/evince-document-viewer-failed-to-execute-child-process-nemo-permission-deni/363188) but that feels wrong.
- Other invite to [put evince in aa-complain mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/867749) which feels wrong, too.
- What to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is solved immediately by modifying `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/fonts` to include a line like this:

```
/complete/template/path/to/userdirs/*/.cache/fontconfig          r,
```

This applies to all users (`*` being at the part of the path that is the user login).

This feels correct.  Is it?